# How can we create a entry form using Formtemplates?

Tags: html, css

Step 1: Collect requirements from the client.
Step 2: Complete the design part from the CSS team.
Step 3: Create Entity.
Step 4: You can access the Form template by logging into technical support.
[Create a new form template with template code, template name.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Owkoq.png)

[Select the master type, and form type also fill in the required fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fp0d.png)

1. What is outer Html?
   Ans: An outer HTML defines the outer cover div of an HTML file.
2. What is Inner Html?
   Ans: An Inner HTML defines the cover div which is looping for a field.
3. What is a Template list query?
   Ans: The list query for saved data.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJoMh.png)

**Section in Formtemplates**

We can split the HTML file into multiple sections and the outer part (outer cover div) will keep in the outer HTML.

[We can add fields by clicking Create fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Cbpx.png)
We can also add additional classes, styles, override names,s, etc in the create field.

[We can add a formula with the fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8nEc.png)

[if you want to add functionality with a query we can write the query in the form of template functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fytdM.png)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Collect requirements from the client.
Step 2: Complete the design part from the CSS team.
Step 3: Create Entity.
Step 4: You can access the Form template by logging into technical support.
[Create a new form template with template code, template name.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Owkoq.png)

[Select the master type, and form type also fill in the required fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fp0d.png)

1. What is outer Html?
   Ans: An outer HTML defines the outer cover div of an HTML file.
2. What is Inner Html?
   Ans: An Inner HTML defines the cover div which is looping for a field.
3. What is a Template list query?
   Ans: The list query for saved data.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJoMh.png)

**Section in Formtemplates**

We can split the HTML file into multiple sections and the outer part (outer cover div) will keep in the outer HTML.

[We can add fields by clicking Create fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Cbpx.png)
We can also add additional classes, styles, override names,s, etc in the create field.

[We can add a formula with the fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8nEc.png)

[if you want to add functionality with a query we can write the query in the form of template functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fytdM.png)